# Can I ask questions on how to correct aspects of a particular photo?

Tags: discussion

It sounds like we do not want general critiques in this forum.  That's fine, I know of other places to get that.  I assume the part we don't want is the subjective part, such as emotional impact.

But what about questions on a particular photo asking how to fix particular known problems that are more technical?

For example, I have a photo that I've been told has poor contrast.  I might ask how to improve the contrast when setting up the shot.  Would that be considered on-topic?

Answer (score 4):

I think usually yes, but there's going to be a point where it diverges into opinion.

Running with the contrast example:

- OK: "how do I increase contrast in this photo?"
- Less OK: "what is the appropriate amount of contrast in this photo?"
- Not OK: "what contrast would convey a feeling of sadness and despair in this photo?"

The middle one is definitely a grey area, as it seems like just opinion (and that might be the only kind of answer), but does have some aspects of "technical correctness" for example in black and white printing.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, definitely. :)

If you can, include the problem photo in your question.

Comment: Oh, no worries about including the photo.  I'm not about to ask a question that starts "Imagine a photo with poor contrast..." :)

Comment: Haha, well you never know. This is the Internet after all. :)